# Where should I extract the armeabi-v7a archive when manually installing the Android SDK 4.1 on Windows?

Tags: android, windows, installation

I downloaded all the SDK zip files manually.

The platform, platform-tools, samples, docs and usb-driver are working, but I don't know where to put the system image folder/files.

So anyone with a working 4.1 installation, could you provide me with the file path or perhaps the output of the tree command for the android-sdk folder?

I believe the default location is

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

...\android-sdk\system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a